# Ruby on rails ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Movie Model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :trailerlinks
end
```

Trailer Model:

```
class Trailerlink < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie
end
```

In my movie controller i using this

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @drama = Drama.find(params[:id])
        @link = @drama.trailerlinks
    end
end
```

In my view i using this to show out:

```
<%= @link.id %>
```

Show error like this:

```
undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

How can solve it? Can teach me?

Answer (score 1):

Since `movie` has many `trailerlinks` and I presume `Drama` is an STI association of movie, then `@link = @drama.trailerlinks` will return an **array** of objects in a `CollectionProxy`object, which does not have an `id attribute.

To get `id` attribute, loop through the array or get an object out of there:

In controller:
`@link = @drama.trailerlinks.first`

OR

In view

```
<% @link.each do |l| %>
  <%= l.id %>
<% end %>
```